# Call c# method on click of <li>

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a project which have multiple tabs in

```html
<li id=tab1 class="active"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
<li id=tab2><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
<li id=tab3><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
<li id=tab4><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
```

Each tab have multiple gridviews
When the page_Load is called it executes more than 10 methods which have almost 15 queries, which makes the page really slow.

I want to call the methods on click of the tab
Only relevant method on the relevant TAB

Remeber when the page is postback the `Tab1` becomes the active tab

Comment: Can you please tell me how? Sorry! I am new to C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li runat="server" id=tab1  OnClick="Ontabl1_Click">....</li>
```

Then

```
public void Ontabl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // sender is the li dom element you'll need to cast it though.
}
```

Try like this for Javascript

```
<script>
function fntabl1(str) {
    //your code
}
</script>

<li onclick="fntab1(this.id)" id="tabl">....</li>
```

Comment: <li> tag does not have OnClick="" it can have onclick which is for javascript it it can postback to codebehind

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand, what to put in '//your code' area

Comment: "Only relevant method on the relevant TAB". '//Your code' you need to write the rel event method which binds the GridView realted to the tab

Answer (score 0):

Add runat= server attribute to each  tag. Write OnClick method for each of them. In the click method on server side load the corresponnding gridview.